# New Functional Web Framework with jetty

Tags: spring, spring-webflux

I wanted to setup an example for [New in Spring 5: Functial Web Framework](https://spring.io/blog/2016/09/22/new-in-spring-5-functional-web-framework)
So I set up a `RouteConfiguration`:

```
@Configuration
public class RouteConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    @Bean
    public RouterFunction<?> routerFunction() {
        return route(
                GET("/first")
                , myService::getItemsFirst)
                .and(route(
                        GET("/second")
                        , myService::getItemsSecond));
    }
}
```

I started my application using jetty and at first it seemed to work... until I wanted to call one of my methods: `localhost:8080/first` and it returned a `404`.

Did I define my route configuration wrong or why arent the routes accessible?

**EDIT**

With netty you need to provide a Server Configuration Like the following:

```
@Configuration
public class HttpServerConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public HttpServer httpServer(final RouterFunction<?> routerFunction) {
        final HttpHandler httpHandler = RouterFunctions.toHttpHandler(routerFunction);
        final ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter adapter = new ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter(httpHandler);
        final HttpServer server = HttpServer.create("localhost", Integer.valueOf(this.environment.getProperty("server.port")));
        server.newHandler(adapter);
        return server;
    }
}
```

But I could not find something like this for jetty.

**EDIT 2**

My Dependencies:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
}

dependencyManagement {
    dependencies {
        dependency (group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-consul-discovery', version: '2.0.0.M1')

        dependencySet (group: 'org.hibernate', version: '5.2.8.Final') {
            entry 'hibernate-core'
            entry 'hibernate-entitymanager'
            entry 'hibernate-spatial'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux') {
        exclude module: 'spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty'
    }
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator')

    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-consul')
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-consul-discovery')

    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile('junit:junit')
}
```

Spring-Boot Version: `2.0.0.M3`

Comment: You have a mapping for `/first` but only if the requested content type is `application/json` or `application/json+stream`. So unless you are explicitly specifying that I highly doubt the browser will send either one of those as a content type. Thus a 404 because there isn't a mapping for that combo. At least that is what I suspect.

Comment: i can also put the contentType and the accept out of the code. that wont change a thing, see my updated post.

Comment: Enable debug logging (start with `--debug` ) and see if the bean gets detected and the routes mapped. Make sure that the `RouteConfiguration` is in a package covered by the `@ComponentScan` from Spring Boot.

Comment: The bean is getting detected and the package is covered by `@ComponentScan`. Do I need a special server configuration when using jetty? with netty you need a configuration. Could not find any informations about jetty. I update my post to show the netty configuration.

Comment: You would have to use a version of Jetty that is Servlet 3.1 compliant and I believe it does some auto detection when using it. (It should do the same for Netty I believe). However all that autoconfig is still in milestone stages so I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Yes. We are using Jetty 9.4.6 which is 3.1 compliant: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Starting/Jetty_Version_Comparison_Table

Comment: Which dependencies do you have on your class path?

Comment: Added dependencies to post.

Comment: Is there something pulling in the `spring-webmvc` dependency? Which would disable the reactive runtime.

Comment: You can force specifying application type as reactive.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
  SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(AgentApplication.class);
  application.setWebApplicationType(WebApplicationType.REACTIVE);
  application.run(args);
 }
```

Comment: @Kane this is a very nice information and it is working! The 404 arent occuring anymore. The only problem now is..... it does not work together with consul discovering :( But that ofcourse... is another problem.

Comment: @Mulgard could you answer your own question then? This would definitely help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the comments, it seems this was an issue with dependencies bringing  `spring-boot-starter-web`; if it is present, a Spring MVC application is started by Spring Boot.

There's a way to explicitly tell Spring Boot the type of the application, in the main Application class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(AgentApplication.class);
    application.setWebApplicationType(WebApplicationType.REACT‌​IVE);
    application.run(args);
}
```

Comment: Yes, but keep in mind that there are still some spring-boot tools which cant handle reactive types. There is still much to do.